# SwiftUI: Handling navigation & UINavigationController's methods equivalents

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui

---

I am currently working on a SwiftUI app and the navigation seems to be our biggest problem. I was wondering if you came up to some equivalents of UINavigationController's `popToViewController(VC)` and `popToRootViewController()` ?

And also how you are handling the navigation at all considering that our aim is to be controlled by a different module - something like a Coordinator or Flutter's Navigator?